# In how many ways we can create a positive number less than 1000 and divisible by 5 (no repeating)?

Tags: combinatorics

**In how many ways we can create a positive number less than 1000 and divisible by 5 (no repeating)?**

Comment: How many less than 10, 25, 100; see a pattern?

Answer (score 1):

All the possible solutions can be divided into three different categories: one-digit, two-digit and three-digit numbers. I'll go over every category and explain the approach to reach a number that is divisible by 5 and under a 1000.

The one-digit numbers are self-explanatory. There are nine possibilities: 1, 2, 3, ... , 8 and 9. Only five is divisible by five, obviously. The total of one-digit numbers is thus narrowed down to one possibility.

The two-digit numbers contain two positions on which elements can be placed. Since you asked for no repeating numbers, we start with every possible first digit, except for five. On the first position, there are eight possible elements (1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8 and 9) and on the second position there are two possible elements (0 and 5, since a number is divisible by five if the last digit is a 0 or a 5). This makes 8 times 2 possibilities, so thus far 16 possibilities. If the first digit is a 5, then the second digit can only be a 0 to be divisible by 5 and to avoid repetition. This makes the grand total of two-digit possibilities 17.

For the three-digit numbers, we can use the previous outcomes to determine the exact amount of possibilities. Since no repetition is allowed, numbers like 110 and 115 are erased from this amount. This clears out 2 possibilities for every hundred as a first-digit. Again, we cover 5 as a first digit later on. The first digit now can be 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8 or 9, a total of 8 possibilities. The following digits allow for 16 possibilities, since we already cleared out the first two digits being the same. There are 8 times 16 possibilities now, which makes 128 in total. For the numbers between 500 and 600, there are 8 possibilities: 510, 520, 530, 540, 560, 570, 580 and 590.

We can now add up everything to determine the exact amount of possibilities: 1 + 17 + 128 + 8 = 154.

Comment: Your solution is correct.  However, it can be done more efficiently by adding the number of cases whose units digit is $0$ to the number of cases whose units digit is $5$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint -

For divisible by 5 last digit should be divisible by 5. And less than 1000 so it can be 1 digit number, 2 digit or 3 digit number.

1 digit number -

Only 5 is 1 digit number.

Total = 1

2 digit number -

First digit can't be 0. So we can choose first digit in 8 ways except 5. Last digit can be 0 or 5. Ways $= 8 \times 2 = 16$

First digit is can't be 0. Then first digit is 5 and last digit is 0. Ways $= 1 \times 1 = 1$

Total = 17

Similarly try for 3 digit number.

**Edit -**

Alternative way.

Case 1 -

1-digit number 1 - 9 = 9. And only 5 is divisible.

So 1-digit number divisible by 5 = 1.

Case 2 -

2-digit number 10 - 99 = 90.

And number divisible by 5 are $\frac {90}{5} = 18$.

But 55 is not included so we left with 17.

So 2-digit number divisible by 5 = 17.

Case 3 -

3-digit number 100 - 999 = 900.

And number divisible by 5 are $\frac {900}{5} = 180$.

But 100, 110, 115, 155, 200, 220, 225, 255, 300, 330, 335, 355, 400, 440, 445, 455, 500, 550, 555, 600, 655, 660, 665, 700, 755, 770, 775, 800, 855, 880, 885, 900,  955, 990, 995 is not included so we left with 180 - 27 = 153

So 3-digit number divisible by 5 = 145.

Total = 1 + 17 + 145 = 163.

Comment: In your second method, you overlooked some three-digit positive integers with repeated digits such as $100$.

Comment: Ok thank you I will edit.